# How to control radio button group?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have radio button group and I have to choose just one it's okey so far but in the same time I want to add class just one if which one has to be checked how could I do it ? I mean if I click current radio button I want add class to it. if I click another button it must remove class another radio button.

By the way I want to change text of label default text and checked text.

**HTML :**

```
 <label>       
   <span>CHOOSE</span><input type="radio" name="group1">
 </label>

 <label>       
   <span>CHOOSE</span><input type="radio" name="group1">
 </label>
```

**JS :**

```
$('input:radio').on("click",function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $(this).parents("label").addClass("arac-secildi");
        $(this).parents("label").find("span").text("CHOOSED");
    }
});
```

**[CodePen example](http://codepen.io/cowardguy/pen/PbXBLa)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Updated CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XNoPWd)**.

You could remove the class from all the other labels on click using `$('label').removeClass("arac-secildi")` then add it to the checked one like :

```
$('input:radio').on("click",function(){
  $('label').removeClass("arac-secildi");
  $('span').text("CHOOSE");

  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $(this).parents("label").addClass("arac-secildi");
    $(this).parents("label").find("span").text("CHOOSED");
  }
});
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$('input:radio').on("click",function(){
  $('label').removeClass("arac-secildi");
  $('span').text("CHOOSE");
  
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $(this).parents("label").addClass("arac-secildi");
    $(this).parents("label").find("span").text("CHOOSED");
  }
});
```

```css
.arac-secildi{
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>       
  <span>CHOOSE</span><input type="radio" name="group1">
</label>
<label>       
  <span>CHOOSE</span><input type="radio" name="group1">
</label>
<label>       
  <span>CHOOSE</span><input type="radio" name="group1">
</label>
```

Comment: great! how about text is that any way to change text if button be checked text must be blabla if is not checked must be xxxx I mean..is there any function for this works like addClass ?

Comment: my label text is "choose" if I checked radio button if will be "choosed" and if I checked another radio button it will be default text I tried but I couldn't it

Answer (score 1):

Or you can do something like this, using the "not" function of jquery:

```
  $('input:radio').on("click",function(){
        $('input:radio').not($(this)).parents("label").removeClass("arac-secildi").find("span").text("CHOOSE");
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $(this).parents("label").addClass("arac-secildi");
            $(this).parents("label").find("span").text("CHOOSED");
        }
    });
```

Here is a jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/dv0Lnohu/3/

```js
$('input:radio').on("click",function(){
          $('input:radio').not($(this)).parents("label").removeClass("arac-secildi").find("span").text("CHOOSE");
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $(this).parents("label").addClass("arac-secildi");
                $(this).parents("label").find("span").text("CHOOSED");
            }
        });
```

```css
.arac-secildi{
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  
 <label>       
   <span>CHOOSE</span><input type="radio" name="group1">
 </label>
  
  
 <label>       
   <span>CHOOSE</span><input type="radio" name="group1">
 </label>
  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
</body>
```